# Steps in Secondary Fermentation

Tags: fermentation, secondary, fruit, secondary-fermentation

I just picked up my Better Bottle Carboy... and will be racking to it in a few days. I have a few questions to ask since I did not use a secondary during my first few batches:
1) Do I add yeast at this point too?

2) Any considerations when I add a fruit puree?

Thanks in advance for any help you guys/gals can send my way!

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to add more yeast.    Assuming that the beer has been in your primary vessel for 1-4 weeks, you'll have plenty of yeast left to consume any additional sugars from the fruit puree.

I would sanitize the bottle and the puree container, add the puree to the bottle, and then rack the beer into the bottle.   This will get the puree stirred into the bottle well.

Comment: thank you for your help! I figured that was the way to do it... but it never hurts to ask!